# How To Remove Leading white space from key-value which is a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have something like:

```
d = {'d':[' Cool Guy', ' Cool Gal']}
```

How do I remove the space inside the key-value so my output would be

```
d = {'d':['Cool Guy', 'Cool Gal']}
```

I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: It's a list, that's in a dictionary if I try to use .lstrip or replace, it isn't working

Comment: u can use `d = {key: [x.strip() for x in val] for key, val in d.items()}`

Comment: @Tryingtolearnpython I think my solution is general for any length dictionary (key wise) and list lengths (value wise)

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'d':[' Cool Guy', ' Cool Gal']}
for key in d:
    d[key] = [ls.strip() for ls in d[key]]
```

Comment: There is also `.lstrip()` if you only want to remove only the leading space and ignore trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'d':[' Cool Guy', ' Cool Gal']}

for k, v in d.items():
    new_d = {k:[elem[1:] for elem in v]}
    print(new_d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'d': ['Cool Guy', 'Cool Gal']}
```

**Logic:**

1. Extract the key (`k`) and corresponding value list (`v`).
2. Loop through its items and ignore first character to form new array.
3. Store new list as the new value of the dictionary.